# Clearing the NTFS Journals in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, ntfs, journaling

I'm using Vista and have several NTFS drives.

Is there any way I can clear the journals and disable further journaling?

Comment: I take it you just got an SSD?

Comment: I'm using a traditional HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up and administrator prompt (search `Command Prompt` in Start menu, right click on option, Run as Administrator) then paste this block in:

```
fsutil usn deletejournal /d C:
```

(You'll have to paste using right click, by the way.) You can do this with every drive letter.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any precautions from doing this?

Comment: My general motto is to **backup your data, or it will end up like the unicorns in Noah's ark**.